# Regular Expressions difference between [0-9] and [0-9.]

Tags: python, regex

I just started looking into regular expressions, and was wondering what the difference is between the following:

```
def test():
    string = "He was 75 in the 1985sdfdhs 45"
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+', string)
    print(y)

test()
```

and this

```
def test2():
    string = "He was 75 in the 1985sdfdhs 45"
    y = re.findall('[0-9.]+', string)
    print(y)

test2()
```

To my understanding the "." matches any character, so I would have thought the output for test2 would equal ['75', '1985sdfdhs', '45'], instead they are both ['75', '1985', '45'].  Just trying to figure out whats going on here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When within the brackets `[` and `]`, the dot is considered a character by itself. So the second regex will match 0-9 as well as the decimal dot. The brackets denote a character set and will match one of the characters in the set (which is why the `.` is considered a character and not a specifier).

**EDIT**: As an additional note, while you're learning about RegEx, I recommend https://regex101.com/ which will break down each part of the RegEx for you.

Comment: Perfect thank you, that explains why '[0-9]+.+' outputs ['75', '1985sdfdhs', '45'], because the "." is outside the brackets so it is considered part of regex, and not a period.  And awesome, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

[ ] here signifies a set. Anything inside it is considered as an element of the set. So [0-9.]  means numbers from 0 to 9 and a '.' character. If you might have used " [0-9].+ " then you would have got your expected result from test 2.

You can try https://regex101.com to check you regex pattern quickly and then use them in your code anywhere.